# Displaying all .png images with display command in linux

Tags: linux, terminal, display

To display an image in a folder, one uses display image.png

If I want to open all .png files in a subfolder, I tried display *.png, but did not work.

How could this be done in interactive shell?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
for f in ./subdir/*.png; do
display $f &
done
```

It should loop through all your files inside the subdir and display all *.png files, starting each as a background process.